# Spring Kotlinx Serialization ExceptionHandler HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, spring-mvc, serialization

Hi I am currently encountering a problem with Spring serialization using kotlin serialization.
I have made a few exception classes that are all serializables, and I have configured spring to use kotlinx serialization.

```
val GLOBAL_JSON = Json {
    serializersModule = SerializersModule {
        include(DEFINITION_EXCEPTION_SERIALIZERS_MODULE)
    }

    encodeDefaults = true
    ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebMvcConfiguration: WebMvcConfigurer {
    private val converter = KotlinSerializationJsonHttpMessageConverter(GLOBAL_JSON)

    override fun configureMessageConverters(converters: MutableList<HttpMessageConverter<*>>) {
        converters.add(this.converter)
    }
}
```

and I have a controller which throws an error that I handle with this controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionControllerAdvice: ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {
    @ExceptionHandler(value = [DefinitionException::class])
    fun handleDefinitionException(exception: DefinitionException): ResponseEntity<DefinitionException> {
        //error(GLOBAL_JSON.encodeToString(exception))
        return ResponseEntity.status(exception.httpCode).body(exception)
    }
}
```

However I think there is a problem related to Spring serializing my response because I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: No acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:322) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invocation failure
Controller [net.astraunot.web.central.restapi.v1.web.controller.ProfileController]
```

When I replace the body by a String everything works, and my exception is serializable because `error(GLOBAL_JSON.encodeToString(exception))` return `{"type":"profile-property-format","message":"Property name isn't formatted correctly. Name exceed max length (16).","property":"name","hint":"Name exceed max length (16)."}`

It should have serialized my exception and I don't really know what to try since it happens on the Spring side.

I tried to modify accept content type when I test my application:

```
mvc.post(url) {
   accept = MediaType.ALL
}
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried to see if it was coming from Spring but I don't think so because

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = [DefinitionException::class])
    fun handleDefinitionException(exception: DefinitionException): ResponseEntity<Profile> {
        val exception2: DefinitionException = ProfilePropertyFormatException("a", "b")
        val profile = Profile(UUID.randomUUID(), "test")

        return ResponseEntity.status(exception.httpCode).body(profile)
    }
```

works but when its an exception with polymorphism it doesn't work